# Determine all functions $f(z)$ analytic in the set $\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ that fulfil the condition

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Determine which functions $f(z)$ analytic in $\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ fulfil $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))=1$.

I have solved the question, but I want to make sure that it's fine.

*First solution: I thought about it and technically it is wrong by $u(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$*:
In the condition given, $\operatorname{Re}(f(z)) = 1$ for every $z$ on the unit circle in the complex plane. So, if $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are the real and imaginary parts of the function, respectively, then $u(x,y) = 1$ for all $z$ on the unit circle (since there is infinite values for $(x,y)$ and this is the vital point that I am not sure about).
Then by the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we get that $v(x,y)$ is constant.

Second solution:

1. If $f(z)$ analytic in domain $D$ and continuous on its boundary then the maximum of $|f(z)|$ is on the boundary.
2. If a function $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and non-zero on the boundary of $D$, then the minimum value of $|f(z)|$ on $D$ must occur on the boundary. And by sandwich theorem we get that $f(z)$ is constant.
   So from this point we define new function, $$h(z) = e^{f(z)}$$ and we take arbitrary $z_0$ on $\partial_ D$ , $\begin{equation}\min |e^{f(z)}| = |e^{u}| = e\end{equation}$ and same for the Max, so eventually we will get \begin{equation}
   \min\left|e^{f(z)}\right| \leq |h(z)| \leq \max\left|e^{f(z)}\right|
   \end{equation}
   If we apply the logarithm to both sides of the equation, we get:
   \begin{equation}
   \log\left(\min\left|e^{f(z)}\right|\right) \leq \log\left(h(z)\right) \leq \log\left(\max\left|e^{f(z)}\right|\right)
   \end{equation}
   And by applying the logarithm property on both sides we will get $u = 1$,
   then we use Cauchy Reimann equations since the function is analytic , $u_x$ = $v_y$= $0$, $u_y$ = $-v_x$ = $0$, integral on both sides we will get $v =$ constant.

Comment: For a complex variable $z$, the expression $z\le 1$ makes no sense. Did you mean $|z|\le 1$?

Comment: yes I will edit it now

Comment: @MayyasHaj There were a huge number of typos in your post. I tried to fix them. Is it what you liked to say? Your last sentence: "And by sandwich theorem we get that $f(z)$ is analytic." Are you sure you wanted to say *analytic*?

Comment: Thank you for the edit

Comment: @MayyasHaj Your first solution is correct. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is only $1$ on the boundary $|z|=1$ but not in the interior of the circle. You found that $f(z)=1+\mathrm{i}\,c$ with some $c \in \mathbb R$. By the way, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ cannot be the real part of any analytic function since it is not harmonic.

Comment: You meant to say the second one is correct?